# Issue with future date code in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am using the follow script to display a future date on my website but i just realized that now that we are at the end of the month my future date is not accurate as it is only adding days to the day and not the date. So what I would like it to display is the November 4th but it is displaying as October 35th. any detailed suggestions would be appreciated as my coding abilities are limited.

here is my current script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var months = new Array( "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth();
var day = currentTime.getDate() +4;
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
document.write(months[month] + " " + day + ", " + year);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Try `currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate())` this will change `currentTime` to be 4 days from now and will handle rolling over the months and / or years. Do it *before* you try and get the day, month or year.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
currentTime.setDate(currentTime.getDate() + 4);  // now currentTime is 4 days in the future!
var month = currentTime.getMonth();              // this (as of writing) will now be november
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
```

This takes care of all the rolling over of months and years as well.

Answer (score 0):

I always resort to using the lib [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) when it comes to date & time.

In code that would be:

```
var futureDate = moment().add(4, 'days');
console.log(futureDate.format()); // Customize format after need
```